# How to use JMeter test component (i.e. sampler or assertion) twice in same test?

Tags: testing, jmeter

GUI mode is interesting. 
At this moment I create one component (i.e. assertion) and then copy and paste it on every place where it's needed. But if I change assertion in some place I must manually change all same assertions in all other places where its used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reusability in Jmeter can be done in 4 ways:

- include controller when you want to reuse a subset of test (login, logout)
- module controller to reuse controller in existing plan
- user defined variables that you can reuse everwhere
- xxx defaults for some samplers ( Ftp, Http...)

But in your particular case you can do it as below.

Define your expression as a var in User Defined Variable then use it in your assertions:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables

For sampler use Http Request Defaults to factor what is common between them.

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults

Note that to find elements with same regexp expression yoy can use search feature which highlights results of search.

Comment: But what should I do if I need repeatedly use HTTP sampler?

Comment: I has understood that there aren`t exists simple way for re usege of any test element. They all need different scenario. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO The cleanest way to reuse components is to use [ModuleController](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) with jMeter Plugins' [ParametrizedController](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ParameterizedController/).

The ParametrizedController link above will explain you how it's done.

Comment: ParameterizedController link is now http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ParameterizedController/